# Excel vba how to copy sheet with all formatting & page setup

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen quite a few examples for making a full copy of a worksheet but none of them are working for me. In my case the sheet has to go into a new workbook. In my actual code wb is defined global and the workbook is created in another sub that called this one.

```
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Add()
  Dim newtab as Worksheet

  With ActiveWorkbook
   .Sheets("Sample Attendance").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
   Set newtab = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count - 1)
  End With
```

didn't work.

Likewise

```
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sample Attendance").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
  Set newtab = wb.Sheets("Sample Attendance")
  newtab.Name = tabname
```

both methods return after the Copy statement.

I've been moderately successful with this:

```
  Set newtab = wb.Worksheets.Add
  newtab.Name = tabname
  Set Attendance = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample Attendance")
  Attendance.Range("A:BB").Copy Destination:=newtab.Cells(1, 1)
```

which works. But then I have to copy all of the PageSetup across which is giving me fits and takes forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems with your 1st piece of code...

1. You are using `Activeworkbook`. When you add a new workbook, the new workbook becomes your active workbook :)
2. The second problem is the DOT before `.Sheets.Count` in `wb.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)`. why pick the count from the workbook you are copying?

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim thiswb As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim newtab As Worksheet

    Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add()

    With thiswb
        .Sheets("Sample Attendance").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        Set newtab = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count - 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
Sub SheetCopier()
    Dim OriginalWB As Workbook
    Dim NewWB As Workbook
    Set OriginalWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Add
    Set NewWB = ActiveWorkbook
    OriginalWB.Sheets("qwerty").Copy Before:=NewWB.Sheets(1)
End Sub
```