# How to copy the page setup from worksheets to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can I copy the page setup, including the RightHeaderPicture from worksheet to another using VBA?
Can someone help me here?
Regards,
Antony Terrence

Comment: Do some research using Google, I am sure you will find the answer. Check this answer in SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794284/excel-vba-how-to-copy-sheet-with-all-formatting-page-setup

Comment: Thanks Paresh. I did search Google before posting my question, but in vain. I haven't got the answer yet.:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit bare-bones but you will get the idea by the time you have finished!

Apparently there is no easy way to copy the PageSetup object in its entirety so, assuming the workbook is open try the following:

```
Sub cpyPS()
Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTO As Worksheet

Set wsFrom = Sheets("From")
Set wsTO = Sheets("To")

    With wsTO.PageSetup
        'there are nearly 50 properties
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = wsFrom.PageSetup.AlignMarginsHeaderFooter
        .BlackAndWhite = wsFrom.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite
        .BottomMargin = wsFrom.PageSetup.BottomMargin
        '
        '
        .LeftMargin = wsFrom.PageSetup.LeftMargin
        '
        '
        .Orientation = wsFrom.PageSetup.Orientation
        '
        '
        .PaperSize = wsFrom.PageSetup.PaperSize

        .RightHeaderPicture.Filename = wsFrom.PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture.Filename
        .RightMargin = wsFrom.PageSetup.RightMargin
        '
        '
        .TopMargin = wsFrom.PageSetup.TopMargin
        '
        '
        .Zoom = wsFrom.PageSetup.Zoom
    End With

End Sub
```

The full list of properties to consider is [provided here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841253(v=office.15).aspx).

Never mind, perhaps write it once as a function and post back for all to use?

You could always copy the whole sheet and rename it if this is doable for you.  The properties will be 'taken across' as it were.

Comment: I would just copy the page in it's entirety and rename it like @barryleajo mentioned at the end of his post. Way less headache and way less code to write.

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks a lot for this wonderful solution. I just want the header stuff and won't be copying entire worksheet as each will have different objects in them. In fact, i just wanted the RightHeaderPicture copied from sheet to another. Your code gives me a good idea. I was trying to use FileDialog to upload a picture (logo) but it does not work. Thank you, Michael too.

Answer (score 5):

Based on barryleajo's answer, I came up with this code:

(The commented areas caused runtime errors)

```
Sub copyPageSetup(fromSheet, toSheet)
With toSheet.PageSetup
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = fromSheet.PageSetup.AlignMarginsHeaderFooter
'    .Application = fromSheet.PageSetup.Application
    .BlackAndWhite = fromSheet.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite
    .BottomMargin = fromSheet.PageSetup.BottomMargin
    .CenterFooter = fromSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter
'   .CenterFooterPicture = fromSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture
    .CenterHeader = fromSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader
'   .CenterHeaderPicture = fromSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeaderPicture
    .CenterHorizontally = fromSheet.PageSetup.CenterHorizontally
    .CenterVertically = fromSheet.PageSetup.CenterVertically
'   .Creator = fromSheet.PageSetup.Creator
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = fromSheet.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter
    .Draft = fromSheet.PageSetup.Draft
'    .EvenPage = fromSheet.PageSetup.EvenPage
'    .FirstPage = fromSheet.PageSetup.FirstPage
    .FirstPageNumber = fromSheet.PageSetup.FirstPageNumber
    .FitToPagesTall = fromSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall
    .FitToPagesWide = fromSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide
    .FooterMargin = fromSheet.PageSetup.FooterMargin
    .HeaderMargin = fromSheet.PageSetup.HeaderMargin
    .LeftFooter = fromSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter
'    .LeftFooterPicture = fromSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooterPicture
    .LeftHeader = fromSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader
'    .LeftHeaderPicture = fromSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture
    .LeftMargin = fromSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = fromSheet.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter
    .Order = fromSheet.PageSetup.Order
    .Orientation = fromSheet.PageSetup.Orientation
'    .Pages = fromSheet.PageSetup.Pages
    .PaperSize = fromSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize
'    .Parent = fromSheet.PageSetup.Parent
    .PrintArea = fromSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea
    .PrintComments = fromSheet.PageSetup.PrintComments
    .PrintErrors = fromSheet.PageSetup.PrintErrors
    .PrintGridlines = fromSheet.PageSetup.PrintGridlines
    .PrintHeadings = fromSheet.PageSetup.PrintHeadings
    .PrintNotes = fromSheet.PageSetup.PrintNotes
    .PrintQuality = fromSheet.PageSetup.PrintQuality
    .PrintTitleColumns = fromSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleColumns
    .PrintTitleRows = fromSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows
    .RightFooter = fromSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter
'    .RightFooterPicture = fromSheet.PageSetup.RightFooterPicture
    .RightHeader = fromSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader
'    .RightHeaderPicture = fromSheet.PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture
    .RightMargin = fromSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = fromSheet.PageSetup.ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter
    .TopMargin = fromSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin
    .Zoom = fromSheet.PageSetup.Zoom
    End With
End Sub
```