# Excel VBA Store PageSetup Object

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to store a PageSetup object that will be used to set the printing options of a worksheet? I tried with this code but I'm getting an error that says: Object variable or With block variable not set. This is how I'm doing it since I need to setup the settings first from a form and loop through some sheets using the printing settings stored in this object.

```
Dim curPageSetup As PageSetup

curPageSetup.paperSize = xlPaperA3
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27348464/2727437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all that you want to do is change the `PaperSize` for all of the sheets in your book, you can do it like this

```
Sub SetPaperSize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA3
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Not necessary to store `PageSetup` to change its attributes

Comment: Just a follow up question.. When I set FitToPagesTall and FitToPagesWide to 1, does it auto scale the sheet so that it fits the paper size that was chosen?

Comment: @VinceGonzales "`PageSetup.FitToPagesTall` sets the number of pages tall the worksheet will be scaled to when it's printed. Applies only to worksheets." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-fittopagestall-property-excel

Comment: @VinceGonzales So I would think so!