# Copy worksheet after another and conserve the format (colours)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to know how I can copy with format (colours) the content of a worksheet after another using special paste.

My code:

```
Application.Interactive = False
btVar = Sheets.Count
Worksheets("sheets1").copy after:=Worksheets(("sheetsB" & btVar))
btVar = btVar + 1
ActiveSheet.Name = ("sheetsB" & btVar)
```

with this code the new sheet `"sheetsB" & btVar` is a copy of `"sheets1"` but without conservig the format (colours of some cells).

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel vba how to copy sheet with all formatting & page setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794284/excel-vba-how-to-copy-sheet-with-all-formatting-page-setup)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will copy "Sheet1" , will paste it at the end, and will rename it to "Sheet" & number of sheets in this workbook.

*Example*: Let's say you have 3 sheets, you copy "Sheet1", it's placed after "Sheet3" (ot whatever is the name of your last sheet), and it renames it to "Sheet4" (since now the count of sheets is 4).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheet_andFormat()

Application.Interactive = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheets" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai Rado for your answer, but the my problem is how to conserve the same format of sheet1 when copying tipically the colours of some cells ?????! Do I need to use Paste special ????

Comment: @ChL this copies the entire sheet as it is, cell colors, cell's font colors, borders, everything just as it is